# ¿cual archivo .ini utiliza php (-develoment o -production)?

Tags: php

estoy utilizando php en Windows 10, hasta el momento he estado trabajando sin problemas, debo aclarar que estoy trabajando en un  proyecto personal que posteriormente deseo publicar.

Lo que me trae de vuelta es el siguiente problema, necesito realizar una modificación al archivo ".ini" de php, hasta el momento solo había dejado los dos archivos

> php.ini-development y
>   php.ini-production

sin modificarlos y comencé a trabajar de esa forma, ahora que necesito modificar el archivo ".ini", me sucede que:

1. no se cual de los dos debo modificar xD.
2. si modifico *"php.ini-development*" o "*php.ini-production*", ¿debo eliminar el "**-devolement"** o "**-production**" y dejarlo como "php.ini" y ya?.
3. cual archivo a estado usando el motor de php hasta el momento, (no tengo idea cual este usando :( ), me explico esta usando  "*php.ini-development*" o "*php.ini-production*", para la configuración.

se que tal vez  son 3 preguntas en una pero realmente agradezco me puedan ayudar con este pequeño problema.

Gracias.

Comment: Debes elegir uno, copiarlo y renombrarlo a `php.ini`. Si en esa instalación vas a desarrollar, deberías considerar usar el `php.ini-development`

Comment: ok, @Marcos debo entender que la configuración de `php.ini-development`, es por defecto una configuración para desarrollo. diferente de la de producción. Por otro lado, ¿sabes cual de los dos archivos a estado usando "php" hasta el momento.??.

Comment: Si tu server (`apache`) ya esta corriendo puedes creas un archivo con [`phpinfo`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.phpinfo.php) y al acceder a este podrás encontrar en `Loaded Configuration File` el `path` completo al archivo `.ini` que se esta usando. ¿Estas usando una instalación manual,  `XAMPP` o algo parecido?

Comment: Hola @Marco, gracias por la respuesta, si estoy utilizando una versión de instalación manual de  [Apache Lounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/). observe el archivo phpinfo, con la siguiente informacion: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\WINDOWS`  y  `Loaded Configuration File  (none)`. con esta información ya puedo hacer algo, Gracias mas adelante subiré la respuesta.

Comment: todo depende de lo que vayas a hacer... incluso... variara segun lamopinion de cada desarrollador...

Answer (score 0):

voy a resumir que me paso, hay que asegurarse de que en el archivo `httpd.conf` de Apache este incluida `PHPIniDir "tu_ruta_donde_estaphp"` [ver](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=822), con esto cuando se abre el archivo `phpinfo`, debería aparecer `Loaded Configuration File ruta_en_la_que_estaphp`, (en mi caso) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] de esta forma cuando se inicia el servidor se inicia php con la configuración del archivo .ini que tengamos en nuestra ruta

Answer (score 0):

En el phpinfo aparece la ruta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Igual llego 4 años tarde.
Pero me pasaba exactamente la misma duda. Cuál de los dos archivos debía escoger? Pues la respuesta es ninguno de los dos xDD
El archivo php.ini está, solo que el señor Windows decide no mostrarle la extensión, así como en otros sí...
Yo estaba intentando instalar un debuger de php para visual studio.
Es más, hice phpinfo(); y evidentemente, salía la ruta php\php.ini :D

Pero vamos, para quien le pueda servir ahorrarse búsqueda, pues ahí va:

(Nótese, que lo de quitar la selección a archivos ocultos ya lo había probado).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tachán, ahí está.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/362654)

Answer (score -2):

no es ningino de los dos el que estas buscando, para encontrarlo en la ventana donde estas buscando el php.ini debes ir a

> vista>opciones>cambiar opciones de carpeta y busqueda>ver
> Ahi vas hasta abajo y le quitas la seleccion al que dice ocultar extensiones de archivos para tipos de archivo conocido

luego de eso busca de nuevo el php.ini y va a aparecer

Comment: Tu respuesta tampoco es correcta. Para iniciar, cuando se configura un servidor de PHP, se renombra el archivo `-development`, mientras que en un servidor de producción se usa el archivo `-production`.